# How can I get the current UTC time in a Lua script?

Tags: lua, timezone, utc

How can I get the current UTC time using a Lua script and convert it to human readable text?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try `os.date("!%c")`. Here `!` means UTC and `%c` means full date in standard format. For other options, see http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.date.

```
curTime = os.time(); print("os.date(): "..os.date('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S', curTime));  
print("os.date(!): "..os.date('!%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S GMT', curTime))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, here is some sample code that expands on the use of `!`:  ```cutTime = os.time(); print("os.date(): "..os.date('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S', curTime));  print("os.date(!): "..os.date('!%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S GMT', curTime))```

Comment: @TzunghsingDavidWong - Please edit the answer to incorporate your comment into it. Comments get deleted many times.