# Roblox timing system only gives you local time

Tags: lua, roblox

so I have been toying around with this analog clock, and I've attempted to find the answers online but found none. What I basically want this clock to do is pretty much reference GMT time and not the time on my computer because I am trying to make a game that shows all the times in the world. But I cannot do that because if I added 6 hours to show German time, it would correctly tell the time for me, but it would not for anyone in a different time zone. What should I change in my code?

```
    local sp = script.Parent
local Clock = sp.Clock
local HourArrow = Clock.Hour
local MinArrow = Clock.Min
 SecArrow = Clock.Sec

while true do
    local t=tick()
    local hour=(((t/60)/60)/12)%1
    local minute=(hour*12)%1
    local mint = math.floor(minute*60)
    local second= math.floor(((minute*60)%1)*60)
    HourArrow.Rotation = 180+(hour*360)
    MinArrow.Rotation = 180+(mint*6)
    SecArrow.Rotation = 180+(second*6)
    wait(1)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current script is unnecessary.

```lua
myTime = os.time{year=1970,month=1,day=1,hour=0} --current time in seconds from jan 1 1970 midnight
hoursToMove = 1 --how many hours to move forward
myTime = hoursToMove*60*60 + myTime --multiplies by 60 twice to reach minutes then hours
```

`myTime` would now equal the number of seconds passed since `January 1, 1970, 00:00` UTC, plus one hour - change `hoursToMove` to modify how many hours forwards/backwards you want (negative numbers would work).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [os.time](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.date). This allows you to format a time representation as you need. See the manual for `strftime` for format strings. You can also get the time deconstructed in hour, minute, etc. components as a table with `os.date`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "os.date("!%c")" to print UTC time directly, or "os.time()" to get seconds passed from 1 January 1970, 00:00:00 (UTC)

sources : [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982730/how-to-get-current-utc-time-in-lua-script), [Roblox time](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Global_namespace/Basic_functions#os.time), [Roblox date](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Global_namespace/Basic_functions#os.date)

Comment: where exactly would I put the os.date

Comment: `os.date` would be output directly, e.g `print(os.date("!%c"))` would print the date and time.